# @AfterThrowing advice is applied twice

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Can we handle exception like `try-catch` construction with Spring AOP?

When some exception thrown and correspondent aspect contains two advices, with exception class and its superclass,

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "bean(advisedService)", throwing = "e")
void afterThrowingException(RuntimeException e) {}

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "bean(advisedService)", throwing = "e")
void afterThrowingException(Exception e) {}
```

they both are applying.

While in plain `catch(…){}` we can achieve the desired result by ordering from subclass to superclass (from particular to general):

```
try {
    advisedService.doSomething();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {}
catch (Exception e) {}
```

and process handling *ex* of specific type just once✔️

[GitHub](https://github.com/Rostik96/afterthrowingworkstwice) //with [demo test](https://github.com/Rostik96/afterthrowingworkstwice/blob/master/src/test/java/dev/rost/afterthrowingtwice/AfterThrowingTwiceApplicationTests.java)

Comment: that is only natural considering that `RuntimeException` is a **sublass** of the `Exception` class. So in case of `RuntimeException` both pointcuts will apply

Comment: @JAsgarov, obviously, my question is just how to avoid this kind of behavior?
If at all possible.

Comment: one (somewhat ugly) solution would be to save whether the exception was handled and check before applying a pointcut. A better solution would be to throw specific exceptions and not superclass of another exception that you are throwing

Comment: @JAsgarov, thanks for your thoughts on the topic. Hope, that also will be offered out-of-the-box solutions.

Comment: SO is not your personal code writing service - solution is supposed to come from you. We are just here to correct mistakes and point you in the right direction. You are welcome.

Comment: First, speak only for yourself; not as IT-influencer. And there are no mistakes in my question: maybe someone has already solved a similar problem. P.S. "out-of-the-box-solution" does not involve `code writing` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aspect behaves exactly as expected, the way you designed it. Try not to compare apples with pears. In an `@AfterThrowing` advice, you cannot catch/handle exceptions, only do something on top of the exception being thrown, e.g. log them the way you do. Both of your advice methods will fire, because both pointcuts match. So far, so normal.

If you want different behaviour, just change the code. How about this?

```java
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "bean(advisedService)", throwing = "e")
void afterThrowingException(Exception e) {
  System.out.printf(
    "AdvisedServiceAspect %s exception: %s%n",
    e instanceof RuntimeException ? "runtime" : "checked",
    e.getClass().getSimpleName()
  );
}
```

Or if you really want to handle exceptions and not just log them, use an `@Around` advice (made-up example):

```java
@Around("bean(advisedService)")
public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  try {
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }
  catch (RuntimeException e) {
    System.out.println("Runtime exception caught, returning null");
    return null;
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Wrap checked exception in runtime exception", e);
  }
  // Do not handle Throwable, i.e. let it escalate
}
```

Comment: I’d just like to avoid `instanceOf`, `try-catch`, e.t.c. and reach the same behavior through method signatures. Out-of-the-box It seems to be impossible...I'll wait some more time and – in the absence of other answers – accept yours

Comment: I am the current AspectJ maintainer. You can believe me that your idea about how you imagine AspectJ to work is just fantasy. That you wish it to work differently, does not make it come true. I showed you two ways to deal with exceptions, both 100% in line with Java semantics. If you need something else, feel free to develop your own AOP tool.

Comment: I've no more questions) ty, sir